# java heap size error dex2jar android decompile solution?

Tags: java, android, jar, dex, dex2jar

i was working on a android project but my laptop was formatted so i lost all code but i had a signed apk of the file on my phone .. whenever i try to use dex2jar it stops converting mid way with this error. how can i increase the heap size or is there another way out. can i decompile an apk with the key it was signed with

```
C:\~dex2jar>d2j-dex2jar --force
classes.dex
dex2jar classes.dex -> classes-dex2jar.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.objectweb.asm.Type.getInternalName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.V3ClassAdapter.searchEnclosing(V3ClassAdapt
er.java:179)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.V3ClassAdapter.build(V3ClassAdapter.java:13
0)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.V3ClassAdapter.visitField(V3ClassAdapter.ja
va:303)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.acceptField(DexFileReader
.java:603)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.acceptClass(DexFileReader
.java:439)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.accept(DexFileReader.java
:330)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Dex2jar.doTranslate(Dex2jar.java:84)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Dex2jar.to(Dex2jar.java:239)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Dex2jar.to(Dex2jar.java:230)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java
:109)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:34)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a copy of the `d2j-dex2jar.bat` file, and edit it.  Find the line that says this:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%CLASSPATH%" 
            "com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd" %*
```

Change the `-Xmx` parameter to give yourself a larger maxheap size.  Save it, and see if your modified BAT file works better.  (There isn't an elegant way to override the JVM settings in this script.)

---

Apparently ... if you are using `dex2jar-2.0`, the file that you need to edit is `d2j_invoke.bat`.

Comment: i tried this but it gave me another error


dex2jar classes.dex -> classes-dex2jar.jar
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1863680 bytes for card ta
ble expansion
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:~dex2jar-0.0.9.13\hs_err_pid6240.log

Comment: You've not got enough physical memory / swap space to make the heap that large.  Try something smaller.  It may be that this approach won't work at all.  Maybe you need to figure out why dex2jar is using so much memory, and modify it.  (Maybe it is leaking memory ...)

Comment: can't find that line.

@"%~dp0d2j_invoke.bat" com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd %*

Answer (score 4):

if you use `dex2jar-2.0` ,you can find the line that says this:

> java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m *******************************
>        in d2j_invoke.bat instead of d2j_dex2jar.bat